# Angular.js when promise is rejected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here my code snippet-

```
$scope.getfiles = function() {
  Api.file.query().$promise.then(
    function(result){ $scope.getfiles = result; },  //on success
    $scope.commonAjaxErrorHandling("Failed to get  File data.", true)  //on failure
  );
};
```

My doubt is when promise it self fails(when url is incorrect or server is down) then where should i write this line of code?

```
$scope.addErrorAlert("Service is down.Please try again later",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.catch(function(e) {
   $scope.addErrorAlert("Service is down.Please try again later",true);
})`
You can also use `e` parameter as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

```
$scope.getfiles = function() {
  Api.file.query().$promise.then(
    function(result){ 
      $scope.getfiles = result; //on success
    }
  ).catch(err){
    $scope.commonAjaxErrorHandling("Failed to get  File data.", true)  //on failure
  }
```